# How to customize groovy console output in such a way that it is applicable to all the groovy script running?

Tags: groovy

I have been working on this for some time now and have not been able to get to a proper conclusion. I need to customize the groovy console output, for instance, for every output line, I need to show the time and date. And also I need to print the warnings,errors and exceptions in a particular format. And I need this format to be enabled for all the groovy scripts I run on my computer. Is there some thing like a configuration file where I can change the output format and customize it?? Hope I have been able to put across my question properly. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are looking for a logger, e.g. logback: http://logback.qos.ch/